# Datapoints over the rooflines in Intel-Advisor run on Intel-processors

Tags: performance, optimization, intel, hpc, intel-advisor

I am using Intel-Advisor (2024.0 version) on top of a C++ program ran on one MPI-process and 20 OpenMP threads (and MKL threads because the program uses `cblas_zgemv(...)` from this library).

`$ lscpu` returns:

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              20
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-19
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  10
Socket(s):           2
NUMA node(s):        2
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               62
Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v2 @ 2.80GHz
Stepping:            4
CPU MHz:             1197.097
CPU max MHz:         3600.0000
CPU min MHz:         1200.0000
BogoMIPS:            5585.91
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            25600K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-9
NUMA node1 CPU(s):   10-19
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cpuid_fault epb pti intel_ppin ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d
```

The commands I ran to obtain the below graph are:

```
export MKL_NUM_THREADS=20
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=20

source ../../Intel_Advisor_install_dir/advisor/2024.0/advisor-vars.sh

mpirun advixe-cl --collect=survey --project-dir=advisor -- ./solver_intel.x
mpirun advixe-cl --collect=tripcounts --flop --project-dir=advisor -- ./solver_intel.x
```

***I obtain that some datapoints are above the rooflines Intel-Advisor reports.***

Is this possible or is it a bug I am seeing?

If yes, does anyone know why this is the case?

I was thinking of rooflines of the type FMA, but they do not come out from the Advisor analysis by any means ... Is there a way to make these appear on the plot?

Attached is a picture. Please observe the top green datapoints. I would be grateful for any insights into this.
Thank you!
[image]

EDIT: At the moment, I am trying to run the second step of the data-collection as:

```
mpirun advixe-cl --collect=tripcounts --flop --enable-cache-simulation --project-dir=advisor -- ./solver_intel.x
```

EDIT2: Now, after the second step of the data collection, I do not get any datapoint above the rooflines:
[image]

Comment: You can easily estimate the theoretical maximum FLOPS on this (11-years old) CPU. IB-EP CPUs support only AVX, and not AVX-2 nor even FMA instruction sets. This means they have separate MUL and ADD AVX SIMD units (though AFAIK both can run simultaneously). AFAIK INT/FP SIMD stacks are both 128-bit wide in practice (despite the support of AVX). Thus, such a CPU is pretty bad for codes doing a lot of SIMD FMA operations (since nowadays Intel Xeon CPU have 512-bit FMA units and AFAIK high-end ones have 2 of them -- so 8x-16x more FLOPS).

Comment: Based on this, with 10 cores, a 2.8 GHz base freq and 128-bit non-FMA operations, you should reach up to `2.8*10*128/64*2=112 GFlops`. At 3.6 GHz, it should be 144 GFlops. That being said, the actual frequency may be lower than that (because of the thermal constraints). The number you get are substantially higher, so I guess the information about 128-bit stacks is wrong or the tool reports wrong informations (it might include the shuffle as Flops causing a misleading 50% increase). With 256-bit stacks, results should be 2x bigger. You can check the actual frequency with `perf`.

Comment: So FMA are likely not the issue unless the tool makes wrong assumptions (who know... except Intel). Note that "Default: Float" is selected while the computation (`cblas_zgemv`) AFAIK uses double-precision only. Besides, SMT (hyperthreading) should not be much useful on this CPU because IB CPUs are not able to schedule computing instructions particularly efficiently (it is certainly only useful if your matrix is huge and the memory instructions significantly impact the execution time).

Comment: @JérômeRichard, thanks so much for all this. Why do you work with 10 cores in the calculations? I used one entire node, that is, 20 cores. Shouldn't we multiply as ```20 * 2.8 * 128/64*2 = 224 GFlops``` ? There is no option of double-precision, only FLOAT, INT, or FLOAT+INT in the Intel-Advisor-GUI. I think this includes both SP and DP.

Comment: @JérômeRichard, also please have a look at the second graph I posted: there it reports a slighly less DP-Vector Add peak: 156 GFLOPS ...

Comment: From page 76 of: https://www.intel.com/content/dam/develop/external/us/en/documents/advisor-user-guide.pdf. it seems it does not count shuffles as FLOPS?

Comment: @JérômeRichard: Ivy Bridge has 1/clock 256-bit SIMD `vmulps` *and* 1/clock 256-bit SIMD `vaddps` on a different port, full-width execution units.  The part that's only 128-bit wide is load/store (2 load units and one store-date unit, but only 2/clock address calculation, so (2 load + 1 store) x 128-bit per clock can only be achieved with 256-bit instructions that only need an address calculation every other clock.  (And misalignment has a big penalty for 256-bit load/store.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Ok. I was unsure about this point. It explains the mismatch compared to the results. This is confirmed by [wikichip](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/sandy_bridge_(client)) (though I find this not very clear for a non-native speaker). Thank you. Thus, this is `2.8*10*256/64*2=224 GFlops` for codes doing intensive FMA-like operations.

Comment: @velenos14 Oh I did not see that there are 2 sockets. Note `hwloc-ls` is generally less ambiguous and more precise to get the hierarchy of HPC nodes ;) . With two socket, the theoretical performance is `2.8*20*256/64*2=448 GFlops` assuming the base frequency is used. In practice, `cblas_zgemv` may not reach it for many reasons (on my machine, the best gemm codes reach only ~65% of the theoretical performance).

Comment: @JérômeRichard: https://uops.info/ has experimental testing which also counts uops and ports.  It doesn't explicitly confirm that mul and add can overlap, but they do run on different ports and 1/clock each correctly implies 256-bit full width execution units.  It would be tricky to infer the 3/clock cache access capability from separate measurements of loads + store-address uops competing for ports 2 and 3.

Comment: @JérômeRichard: GEMM usually needs a lot of L1d cache bandwidth, and Ivy Bridge is lacking in that department compared to its FP throughput.  Or I guess with one mul+add per clock matched by one 256-bit load per clock, that's similar to Haswell / Skylake's 2 FMAs per clock with 2x 256-bit loads per clock.  Store throughput is 1/2 a vector per mul+add, again like Skylake.  But L2 and L3 bandwidth in IvB is lower than Skylake.

Comment: Thanks so much for this discussion. Just to mention, the problematic datapoints are not related to ```cblas_zgemv(...)``` ... That is just a part of this very complicated numerical-solver for a PDE I am analyzing ... Albeit an important part, that is measured by ```Intel-Advisor``` and is plotted in the regions of memory-bound kernels or memory-and-compute-bound kernels, thus I guess the tool does a good job at analysing that part. My problems are with those datapoints which go beyond the rooflines. Maybe the timing-measurement of those is inaccurate (because they are executed very fast) ?